# turtlebot3_simulation branch new_gazebo colcon build error (gz sim Harmonic)

Tags: gazebo, ros2, simulation

On a Ubuntu 22.04/x86-64 machine, following [turtlebot3_simulation new_gazebo](https://gazebosim.org/docs/harmonic/migrating_gazebo_classic_ros2_packages) "Migrating ROS 2 packages that use Gazebo Classic", repository. After rosdep, colcon build fails:

$ colcon build --symlink-install
Starting >>> turtlebot3_fake_node
Starting >>> turtlebot3_gazebo
--- stderr: turtlebot3_gazebo
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:23 (find_package):
By not providing "Findgazebo.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "gazebo", but
CMake did not find one.

Could not find a package configuration file provided by "gazebo" with any
of the following names:

```
gazeboConfig.cmake
gazebo-config.cmake
```

### Add the installation prefix of "gazebo" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
"gazebo_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "gazebo"
provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
installed.

Failed   <<< turtlebot3_gazebo [0.49s, exited with code 1]
Aborted  <<< turtlebot3_fake_node [1.28s]

Summary: 0 packages finished [1.86s]
1 package failed: turtlebot3_gazebo
1 package aborted: turtlebot3_fake_node
1 package had stderr output: turtlebot3_gazebo
1 package not processed

[ros_gz Issue 498](https://github.com/gazebosim/ros_gz/issues/498) added to Core Development, but wonder if anyone else has a possible solution.